# Como se usa align-self?

Tags: html, css

Já usei muitos alinhamentos: center, left etc... mas nunca `align-self`. Como posso usá-lo? Gostaria de ver uma aplicação que utilizasse `align-self`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A propriedade `align-self` é utilizada em um item que seja descendente de um elemento com `display: flex;`. Como o nome traduzido sugere, serve para "Auto alinhamento", ou seja, ela irá alinhar somente o item e não seus descendentes.

O que ela irá fazer é ignorar as declarações de alinhamento no elemento pai, alinhando somente o próprio elemento. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: pink;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.item {
    background: #cde;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 16px;
}

.item-self {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">Primeiro</div>
  <div class="item item-self">Segundo</div>
  <div class="item">Terceiro</div>
</div>
```

Por mais que eu tenha declarado no elemento pai (`.parent`) que o alinhamento será `flex-end` (à direita), no segundo elemento eu declaro, com a propriedade `align-self` que ele seja alinhando no início (`flex-start`). Isso faz com que ele ignore a declaração do elemento pai e se auto-alinhe.

Answer (score 1):

`align-self` é usado apenas em modelos que utilizam `display: flex`.

É uma forma aplicada nos itens de um container flex para que você os alinhe dentro do container, que pode ser tanto vertical quanto horizontal dependendo do fluxo do container (seja em colunas ou em linhas).

### Em Linha

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap; /* Note o row */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

### Em Coluna

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap; /* Note o column */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```